# Is it possible to know : Did recipient receive my data SMS message

Tags: android, sms

I'm working on a small application which use data SMS messages.
I know how to manage thé errors during the sending.
I sent several data sms to my contact but I don't know how to know if my data SMS have arrived or not

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

When you call SMSManager.sendTextMessage the deliveryIntent parameter tells you whether it was received.  This does no mean that the user actually saw it, it just means his network received the text.  It may not have been sent to his phone, or it may have been and the user didn't notice the text.  There is no way to tell that the user actually looked at it.